# How to display the fetched data from api in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Data fetched from api is not getting displayed on screen but i am getting the data in console .

data.service.ts

```
    const httpOptions = {
      headers:new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'})
     };

    @Injectable()

    export class DataService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    getuserdetails(){
    return this.http.get<any> 
    ('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1')
    .pipe(map(item => {
        return item;
    }));
    }
   }
```

information.component.ts

```
 export class InformationComponent implements OnInit {
    dataItem:any = {} 

    constructor(private data: DataService) {
    this.data.getuserdetails().subscribe(item=>{
    console.log(item);
    this.dataItem=item;
  });
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

 }
```

information.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="dataItem?.length>=0">           
 <div *ngFor='let x of dataItem'>

   {{x.name}}

 </div>
 </div>
```

Here i am getting the details of user 1 in console but its not getting displayed on main screen.

Comment: Can you show us your data (this.dataItem)

Comment: {id: 1, name: "Leanne Graham", username: "Bret", email: "Sincere@april.biz", address: {…}, …}
address: {street: "Kulas Light", suite: "Apt. 556", city: "Gwenborough", zipcode: "92998-3874", geo: {…}}
company: {name: "Romaguera-Crona", catchPhrase: "Multi-layered client-server neural-net", bs: "harness real-time e-markets"}
email: "Sincere@april.biz"
id: 1
name: "Leanne Graham"
phone: "1-770-736-8031 x56442"
username: "Bret"
website: "hildegard.org"

Comment: Well if dataItem === that data, you cant access .length, since it will return undefined. That is not iterable for javascript

Comment: So instead of <div *ngIf="dataItem?.length>=0">  , what should be the condition

Comment: I would set default dataItem to null, then simply do ngIf="dataItem"
Another thing, you are trying again to iterate in ngFor, there is no need for that, just access data using {{dataItem.name}}

Comment: @Ronit : Did u try putting code in `ngOnInit` ?

Comment: I had changed the condition in html as   <div *ngIf="dataItem">
 {{dataItem.name}} and it worked.

Comment: There you go, glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

Try putting code in `ngOnInit`

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.data.getuserdetails().subscribe(item=>{
  console.log(item);
  this.dataItem=item;
 });
}
```

and verify in html by doing

```
<div *ngIf="dataItem">
   {{dataItem |json }}
</div>
```

Your `*ngFor` wont work as it is not an array

I think this should work. The `constructor` is typescript thing. Try to make make API calls in Angular lifecycle hooks

Comment: The real problem isn't getting the data, it's the fact that the OP is trying to iterate through an object.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what the issues are:

**First** You are trying to get the length of `dataItem`, while it's NOT an array. If you want to check the length, make sure to initialize the dataItem like this `dataItem = []`

```
<div *ngIf="dataItem?.length>=0">
```

**Second** You are trying to iterate (loop) the `dateItem` while it's not an array. If you initialize it as seen in the first bullet above, you would be allowed to do so

```
 <div *ngFor='let x of dataItem'>
```

If you fix these, you will be able to see the data in the template

Have a look at this for a working example https://stackoverflow-55772639.stackblitz.io